# Simple.Odata: how to call a function passing parameters in asp.net mvc request body

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, simple.odata.client

The title is a bit misleading, here is my situation: with postman, i can call the following url issuing a post and my function works:

http://localhost/odataservice/odata/Evaluations(9)/CreateEmptyForm

For it to work, i have to send the following in the body portion:

```
    {
        "@odata.type": "#Common.Data.Client",
        "ClientId": 1
    }
```

My issue arises when i try to replicate this inside my asp.net mvc application. There, im doing

```
    public int CreateRvaForm(int clientId, int evalId, int type)
    {
        var key = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var data = await
                client
                    .For<Evaluation>(Constants.DataService.PLURAL_EVALUATIONS)
                    .Key(evalId)
                    .Function( type==0 ? Constants.DataService.FUNCTION_CREATE_RVA_EMPTY : Constants.DataService.FUNCTION_CREATE_RVA_DUPLICATE)
                    .Set( new{ClientId=clientId} )
                    .ExecuteAsScalarAsync<int>();
            return data;

        }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        return key;
    }
```

Here, the variable client is the Simple.Odata.Client object.

The error i'm getting is something related to route not found; debug shows me that the library is trying to execute the url

http://localhost/odataservice/odata/Evaluations(9)/CreateEmptyForm(clientId=XX). 
I dont have access to modify the odata service.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this text](http://www.odata.org/blog/advanced-odata-tutorial-with-simple-odata-client/) ("Executing functions and actions"), you should rather try using `Action` instead of `Function` since action is POST-based call while function translates to HTTP GET